# SyntaxError when using except in Python

Tags: python

I'm getting the error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` in the line `except httplib.IncompleteRead, e:` for some reason in my code below. Its `Python 3.4`:

```
import httplib
import xlrd
import urllib

try:
    url = 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/results/xls'

#In case of http.client.IncompleteRead Error
except httplib.IncompleteRead, e:
    spot_curve = e.partial
    short_end_spot_curve = e.partial
```

Comment: Which version of Python? Should be `except httplib.IncompleteRead as e:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in Python3 it is:

```
 except httplib.IncompleteRead as e:
```